# Java licensing model : When do I need to pay Sun for using their software?

Tags: java, licensing, midp

Java licensing model : When do I need to pay Sun for using their software?

Comment: Do you mean CDDL? http://www.sun.com/cddl/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 3):

Java,J2ME mobile SDK's from Sun is free and Open Source .As of now you need not pay anything

In future if  Oracle demands Sun not to release its upcoming software as Open source then you may need to pay for licensing .

Comment: Open source may still require licensing, and closed source can be free (as beer). They don't exclude each other.

Comment: I do agree Open source  need licensing , but you need not pay for license , like the Creative commons license which is free :)

Comment: That depends on the license. It can be open source and not free. Either way, this is all theoretical. They wouldn't kill Java like that...

Comment: Its been always a debate between Open source and Closed source, hope we don't get involved  it  here :) .

Answer (score 2):

You **don't need to** pay Sun for using Java (except for [Sun Java Real-Time System](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/realtime/index.jsp) as reminded by [Thorbjørn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/53897/thorbjorn-ravn-andersen) in a comment) but you **might want to** pay for "Mission-Critical Support" and benefit from:

> - Access to critical fixes
> - Long-term support
> - Enterprise features
> - JRE or JDK 6, 5.0, or 1.4.2

See [Java For Business](http://www.sun.com/software/javaforbusiness/) for more details.

Comment: @Thorbjørn Right! Thank you for reminding this. I've updated my answer to mention this exception.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to pay for Java compiler and the JVM, Free Downloadable from   http://www.java.sun.com

Answer (score 0):

Java platform is Free and open source.

Comment: OpenJDK is (AFAIK) an opened version of Sun's Java, but the Sun Java isn't itself open.